# Como retornar quando acabar/manter registro do tempo restante (Timer/Schedulel)?

Tags: java, timer, rmi

Então, estou desenvolvendo um projeto de um jogo que utiliza RMI (cliente/servidor) e precisava gerenciar o tempo limite das jogadas dos jogadores. Por exemplo, se um jogador demorar mais de um minuto para realizar a sua respectiva jogada, ele perde.

As jogadas rodam através de um loop, então eu precisaria checar a cada interação para ver se o tempo acabou. Atualmente estava tentando fazer com as classes Timer/Schedulel, mas não acho uma forma de "salvar" o tempo e verificar quando ele acabou.

**Minha duvida:** Como eu posso salvar/retornar o tempo que está rodando atualmente? Existe algum macete ou alguma classe para isso? Estou tentando alcançar algo como, por exemplo:

```
Timer timer;
int tempoAtual;            // Variável para guardar tempo
boolean isAcabou = false;  // Variável para verificar termino
public Temporizacao(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();                        // Cria um novo Timer
    timer.schedule(new Teste(), seconds*1000);  // set tarefa...
}

class Teste extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        // tempoAtual  -> atualiza tempo atual (?)
        timer.cancel();
        isAcabou = true;  
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Temporizacao(5);        // set tarefa de 5seg

    if(tempoAtual != isAcabou){ // Variável matem o tempo salvo para fazer validações
    System.out.println("Acabou tempo.");
   }
}
```